# Are mice dying in my loft?

Tags: attic, pest-control, mice

I have a downstairs toilet that protrudes from the side of the house. As a result, it has a loft area that is not accessible without cutting into the plasterboard ceiling.

Mice are fairly common in the area due the woodlands opposite the house, so it wasn't a surprise when I started hearing noises in the space above the toilet. What I have noticed recently are some dark orange spots appearing on the ceiling. Some now have droplets hanging from them.

Could this be decomposing mice in the loft space?

It's worth noting that last year some water damage had occurred which has (hopefully) been fixed.

[image: Patch #1]
[image: Patch #2]
[image: Area in question above toilet]

Comment: Is there a bathroom above it? What does it smell like in there? wet mine shaft or ammonia?

Comment: There's a tiled roof above it where it sticks out of the house. No weird smells or anything like that but could be masked due to ventilation from outside.

Comment: Dead mice don't usually exude enough liquid to penetrate the ceiling; they dry out and mummify in a non-leaky attic. It's just barely conceivable that enough live mice with one designated piddle spot could, but not likely as they like to piddle everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the droplets seems to indicate that there is still a water leak in the roof of the bumpout. The discoloration is likely coming from the accumulated dirt and dust in the "attic" part of the bumpout. It is also possible that the discoloration is coming from the leak water pooling in an area where the mice deposited their droppings and then finding its way through the drywall on the bathroom ceiling.

Comment: Thanks! The puddles on my floor this morning confirms the worst. Looks like I need to address that first.